# stacktrace when aborting php (cli)

Tags: php

When my PHP code runs unexpectedly long and consumes a lot of memory, I can abort it. From cli, I use ctrl-C. Is it possible to get a stack trace in this case?

Can I enable and configure xdebug for this? Or pcntl_signal(SIG_INT, ...)? Or can I enable this in phpunit?

It would also be fine to just get the like where I aborted the code without the whole stack trace.

My current work around is to generate output in specific places in the code and to narrow down the lines where the problem occures. I guess there is something more effective.

Situation:
One unit tests hangs and consumes always more memory. So I want to find out where I have the endless loop or endless recursion or ...

Comment: Under Linux you'd need `pcntl_signal()` to catch SIGTERM and SIGINT.

Comment: if you are doing this to profile  your code, you may want to investigate that topic (profiling).  As well, profile with xdebug enabled is a cold waste of time (it consumes a lot of resources)

Comment: I am still interested in better answers. My answer hangs in my real case. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer, which works sometimes.

```php
class AbortError extends \Error // or \Exception, but this could be cought
{
    public static function onSignal($sigNo, $sigInfo)
    {
        throw new self('signal '.$sigNo);
    }
}

if (function_exists('pcntl_async_signals')) {
    pcntl_async_signals(true);
    pcntl_signal(SIGINT, [AbortException::class, 'onSignal']);
    pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, [AbortException::class, 'onSignal']);
    pcntl_signal(SIGUSR1, [AbortException::class, 'onSignal']); // I tried using this signal to maybe avoid normal problematic handing of normal signals
} else {
    // TODO warn
}
```

Sometimes php was stuck too much (or whatever has happened). Then I  sent kill (`kill 11111`) several times, and after several times, the process really aborted, but without printing a stack trace.